# How to check if file has been scp 100% to the remote location

Tags: shell, expect

I am using expect code to scp a file to remote server, but the file transfer gets stop at 8%. How to be sure that 100% file should gets transferred.
Any suggestions please .

Comment: The code gets exit after transferring partial file.

Comment: Tom, thanks for the suggestion but i need to transfer only one file . Does zipping the file will help this in some manner ?